# How does this alignment works? ((n + ZBI_ALIGNMENT - 1) & -ZBI_ALIGNMENT)

Tags: c++, memory, alignment

I'm trying to understand how this alignment works. It should align an uint32 address to its nearest 8 byte aligned address

```
static inline uint32_t
    ZBI_ALIGN(uint32_t n) {
  return ((n + ZBI_ALIGNMENT - 1) & -ZBI_ALIGNMENT);
```

Let's take `n=10`, and `ZBI_ALIGNMENT=8`. The nearest address should be `16`

returns `((10 + 8 -1) & -8) = 17 & -8`

Why this should be aligned?

Comment: Are you asking why `17 & -8` produces `16`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to this formula is that it is only valid if `ZBI_ALIGNMENT` happens to be a power of two, which is not a big deal because alignment requirements tend to fulfil that criteria.

A number being aligned to (aka being a multiple of) a power of two means that all bits smaller than that power of two are set to 0. You can convince yourself of that easily by looking at a few 8-bit numbers:

```
15: 00001111
16: 00010000   <--- aligned to 16
17: 00010001
31: 00011111
32: 00100000   <--- aligned to 16
48: 00110000   <--- aligned to 16
```

Assuming that we have a mask that happens to have only have the bits higher or equal to 16 set, `N & mask`, would be a no-op for all multiples of 16, and give us the *previous* multiple of 16 for all other values.

```
16:          00010000
mask for 16: 11110000

15 & mask -> 00000000 : 0  
16 & mask -> 00010000 : 16
17 & mask -> 00010000 : 16
32 & mask -> 00100000 : 32
```

In order to get the right value directly, we can use `(N + 15) & mask` instead. If `N` is a multiple of 16 already, `N + 15` will land just shy of the next multiple. Otherwise, it will always "bump" the value to the next range. e.g. `1+15 = 16`, `16 + 15 = 31`, etc... This generalises as `(N + (DESIRED_ALIGMENT - 1))`.

So all that's left to figure out is how to calculate the mask for a given desired alignment.

Conveniently, in two's complement representation (which all signed integers have to use), negative values of powers of two happen to be exactly the mask we need.

For 8 bit numbers it looks like this:

```
-1 -> 11111111
-2 -> 11111110
-4 -> 11111100
-8 -> 11111000
etc...
```

So `mask` can simply be computed as `-ZBI_ALIGNMENT`.

Putting all this together, we get:

`((n + ZBI_ALIGNMENT - 1) & -ZBI_ALIGNMENT)`

Comment: As a quick sidenote, I personally prefer to use `~(ALIGNMENT - 1)` instead of `-ALIGNMENT` to create the mask. I find that a lot clearer.